# How many userdata session data can I create for the user?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, codeigniter-2

Codeigniter says only up to 4KB of data can be stored in a cookie. Does that mean each `$this->session->userdata('something');` is one cookie, and i can have an unlimited number of them?
Because I used only ONE userdata session data, and it won't accept any more information since its already 4KB... Will this be fixed if I factor it all out and have many different `$this->session->userdata()`?

Comment: Do you really need more than 4kb of data stored in session?

Comment: Yup. It's for user experience. So I was wondering if each `$this->session->userdata()` is ONE cookie

Comment: Use `nativesession` library

Comment: Would `nativesession` remove the 4KB limit?

Comment: `native session` is like normal php sessions. It stores session data into our server and you can store unlimited data

Comment: I think the `session cookie` is quite smaller, cause it don't store more than a ID on the client, while the real data is stored on the server. If you have a lot of users, you will use a lot of space on your server just for the session data. What kind of data is it you are storing, cause I'm sure we can figure out a better solution! :)

Comment: @Jite - I use sessions to see if the user has seen a particular page. And there are MANY pages.

Comment: I should also note that I am NOT using the database to store sessions. Should I enable database so I can store unlimited data, and get passed that 4KB limit??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no cookie limit to session data because the only thing stored in a cookie is the session ID, a long string of some sort. Actual session data, even when not stored in a DB, is stored in a file on the server identified by the ID. There is no need to use another library. And database session storage is recommended both for speed and security.  As long as your database is secure, your session data will be.  You can actually use sessions without using cookies at all by appending the session ID to the request as a query string, but I wouldn't recommend that unless you want to serve users who have cookies turned off for some reason.